# Why opening of Google Play leaderboards fails?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I open list of available leaderboards with the following code:

```
int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 0;
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(getApiClient()), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

It worked well when I've launched Game Play functionality in my android application. But it started to fail after some time - the activity is displayed for a second, then it starts to load the data (running big circle is shown), but then it closes the activity. Logcat displays the following:

```
06-10 16:21:49.867: I/ActivityManager(555): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.games.ui.client.leaderboards.ClientLeaderboardListActivity: +1s88ms
06-10 16:21:49.987: I/dalvikvm(11424): Could not find method android.view.View.animate, referenced from method euo.a
06-10 16:21:49.987: W/dalvikvm(11424): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3371: Landroid/view/View;.animate ()Landroid/view/ViewPropertyAnimator;
06-10 16:21:49.987: D/dalvikvm(11424): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0020
06-10 16:21:49.987: D/dalvikvm(11424): VFY: dead code 0x0023-0046 in Leuo;.a (Landroid/view/View;)V
06-10 16:21:50.307: D/dalvikvm(720): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1249K, 37% free 6626K/10439K, external 0K/0K, paused 8ms+5ms
06-10 16:21:51.118: W/GLSUser(720): [asb][asb] Permission for org.rosspam to access oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games will be managed locally.
06-10 16:21:51.338: I/dalvikvm(11424): Failed resolving Lbnq; interface 339 'Landroid/content/ComponentCallbacks2;'
06-10 16:21:51.338: W/dalvikvm(11424): Link of class 'Lbnq;' failed
06-10 16:21:51.338: E/dalvikvm(11424): Could not find class 'bnq', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager.<init>
06-10 16:21:51.338: W/dalvikvm(11424): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1347 (Lbnq;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager;
06-10 16:21:51.338: D/dalvikvm(11424): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0030
06-10 16:21:51.338: D/dalvikvm(11424): VFY: dead code 0x0032-0039 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Z)V
06-10 16:21:51.469: V/checkSignaturesLP(555): Fixed by seo
06-10 16:21:51.499: V/checkSignaturesLP(555): Fixed by seo
06-10 16:21:51.499: W/GLSUser(720): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
06-10 16:21:51.549: I/jvq(11208): I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
06-10 16:21:51.549: I/jvq(11208): Retrying request
06-10 16:21:51.689: D/dalvikvm(11208): GC_CONCURRENT freed 341K, 43% free 3874K/6791K, external 0K/512K, paused 7ms+3ms
06-10 16:21:51.839: D/dalvikvm(11208): GC_CONCURRENT freed 520K, 44% free 3871K/6855K, external 0K/512K, paused 3ms+3ms
06-10 16:21:52.009: E/Volley(11208): [19] tk.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards?language=ru_RU
06-10 16:21:52.079: V/checkSignaturesLP(555): Fixed by seo
06-10 16:21:52.109: V/checkSignaturesLP(555): Fixed by seo
06-10 16:21:52.109: W/GLSUser(720): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
06-10 16:21:52.159: D/dalvikvm(11208): GC_CONCURRENT freed 421K, 44% free 3846K/6855K, external 0K/512K, paused 2ms+13ms
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208): Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208): ebw
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at dwp.a(SourceFile:146)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at dfm.a(SourceFile:400)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at dfm.a(SourceFile:238)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at dex.a(SourceFile:302)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at eek.b(SourceFile:34)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at ede.a(SourceFile:60)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesIntentService.a(SourceFile:695)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at bkh.run(SourceFile:101)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-10 16:21:52.179: E/DataHolderOperation(11208):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
06-10 16:21:52.209: D/GameHelper(11197): GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=0, resp=RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED
06-10 16:21:52.209: D/GameHelper(11197): GameHelper: onActivityResult: request code not meant for us. Ignoring.
```

In Google Play Developer Console I see some activity in the leaderboards.
I don't understand why I see `Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.` - it is configured, it worked before.